# Deleting pointer value doesn't panic

Tags: pointers, dictionary, go

Why doesn't the following code panic? `test` is definitely a pointer. With `fmt.Println(people[0].Name)` instead of `fmt.Println(test.Name)` it does panic.

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {

    type Person struct {
        Id   int
        Name string
    }

    people := make(map[int]*Person)

    people[1] = &Person{0, "Name"}
    fmt.Println(people[0].Name)

    test := people[0]
    test.Name = "Name2"
    fmt.Println(test.Name)

    people[0].Name = "Name3"
    fmt.Println(test.Name)

    delete(people, 0)

    fmt.Println(test.Name)
}
```

[Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/RykMy8f1By)

Comment: The code in your question is different from the code in the playground. Which one are you asking about?

Answer (score 5):

The use of the builtin [`delete()`](https://golang.org/pkg/builtin/#delete) removes an entry from a map. It does not delete / deallocate the memory pointed by the value associated with the removed key.

In Go you can't manage memory like this, Go is a garbage collected language and freeing memory is the duty and responsibility of the garbage collector.

Your code doesn't panic because you have a (valid) pointer to a value of type `Person`, and as long as you have it, that person will not become invalid (its memory will not be freed).

When you change your code to `people[0].Name`, then you are indexing a map with a key which is not in the map (because you just removed it with `delete()`), so the result of the [index expression](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Index_expressions) will be the [zero value](https://golang.org/ref/spec#The_zero_value) of the value type of the map, which is `nil` for the `*Person` type. And attempting to refer to the `Name` field of a `nil` struct pointer will cause a runtime panic.